# Crontab doesn't work

Tags: php, linux, cron

I'm trying to install this crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.net/httpdocs/administrator/makeXML.php
```

In crontab there are others scripts installed. 
In `makeXML.php` I inserted a control to understand if crontab is executing:

```
#!/bin/sh
<?php
    $test_file = "../xml_crontab.txt";
    $fp = fopen($test_file, 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "Last xml generation: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n");
    fclose($fp);  
        ...
?>
```

I need to execute this script (`makeXML.php`) every one minute. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to log the output of the cronjob to a log file like this: */1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.net/httpdocs/administrator/makeXML.php > /var/log/crobtab.log

Comment: @CharlieVieillard I will immediately try to log cronjob.

Comment: Good luck, keep us posted!

Comment: `#!/bin/sh
<?php` ?? oO

Comment: @CharlieVieillard I will immediately try to log cronjob.
If I execute in shell that command...something wrong happens:

Warning: fopen() SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is xxx is not allowed to access /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.net ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply the *absolute* path to the file in your script.

Change the line:

```
$test_file = "../xml_crontab.txt";
```

to supply the absolute path to `xml_crontab.txt`.

Remember that `cron` isn't running in the same environment as you are and the script wouldn't be able to locate the file with relative pathname.

Comment: How should I set my Cron Job to work every day at 1PM and 7PM ?